# Can we add custom headers to EWS push notifications callbacks

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS managed library to subscribe for exchange notifications. I need to make sure that exchange adds some custom headers to the push notification request it sends to the callback URL I registered for getting the notifications.
Is there a way to add custom headers? No documentation around it. Does that mean it's not possible?

Comment: Pretty unlikely this is supported/possible. Why would you need these? What would the headers be? What are you trying to do?

Comment: we are routing the requests based on the headers to different servers (prod1 or prod2)..so while subscribing if it was prod1 server which is subscribing the user, callback should also be routed to prod1 and it will happen automatically if exchange adds a custom header to identify prod1.